# Flagging for mod not possible after flagging NAA, even though the option is available

Tags: discussion, flags, user-interface

I just flagged an answer NAA, found out that user had posted the same answer on some other questions as well, flagged those as well since the answer was nonsense on all questions.

Only after doing that, I figured it would make sense to raise a mod flag. I opened the flag dialog, was presented with

[image]

clicked the bottom one, typed my message and hit the button. It said

[image]

I can understand why it says that, but if it's not possible anyway, shouldn't the option to flag for mod be greyed out?

(I don't mean to discuss the order or validity of my actions. This is about something appearing as an option, while it is not.)

Comment: This behavior seemed to change some time in the last year. I'm sure after flagging as NAA it also used to be possible to raise a spam flag, which was useful if you saw a nonsensical answer and later noticed it had a hidden spam link as well.

Comment: Actually, I think this is because the NAA flag was still active. I feel like I saw somewhere that you can only have one active flag on a post at a time, I'll see if I can find that.

Comment: @Kendra ah, that would make sense. But the UI is still a bit confusing then

Comment: Yes, the error at the least could stand some rewording, if not making all the options unavailable. I assume they didn't do the later due to a chance of a flag being cleared just after you open the flag dialog. I personally would settle for rewording the error to something like "You can only have one active flag on a post at a time." I assume this is likely a bit of an edge case, but that doesn't mean people should be confused.